# Ordered RandomSample

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, filtering

This feels like a basic question yet I failed to find an answer.

```
  (*arbitrary list of unique elements, does not need to be sorted*)
list = CharacterRange["a", "h"]; 
n = 5;

RandomSample[ list, n]
```

> {"f", "c", "e", "h", "d"}

`RandomSample` returns a subset which is not ordered with respect to the original `list`.

What is the fastest (bonus points for brevity) way to to get it?

I tried

```
list[[ Sort @ RandomSample[Range@Length@list, n] ]]
```

but I find it too ugly for such basic task, I also tried

```
SortBy[
 RandomSample[list, n],
 PositionIndex[list]
]
```

yet I suspect it may not scale well, it won't work pre V10.0 either.

If there is not anything better I will upvote benchmarks too :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Avoiding `Sort` makes it a bit faster

```
list = "a" <> ToString[#] & /@ Range[10000];
n = 4567;

m1 := list[[Sort@RandomSample[Range@Length@list, n]]]
m2 := SortBy[RandomSample[list, n], PositionIndex[list]]
m3 := Pick[list, RandomSample[Join[ConstantArray[0, n],
                                   ConstantArray[1, Length[list] - n]]], 0]

m1; // RepeatedTiming
m2; // RepeatedTiming
m3; // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.00081, Null}
>   {0.022, Null}
>   {0.00058, Null}

Caching the non-random part only affects `m2`:

```
c1 = Range@Length@list;
c2 = PositionIndex[list];
c3 = Join[ConstantArray[0, n],
          ConstantArray[1, Length[list] - n]];

m1c := list[[Sort@RandomSample[c1, n]]]
m2c := SortBy[RandomSample[list, n], c2]
m3c := Pick[list, RandomSample[c3], 0]
```

> {0.00079, Null}
>   {0.0075, Null}
>   {0.000565, Null}

---

Edit by Kuba, sample length effect:

```
b = Table[{n,
   m1; // RepeatedTiming // First,
   m2; // RepeatedTiming // First,
   m3; // RepeatedTiming // First
   }
  , {n, {1, 5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000}}
  ]



ListLogPlot[
 Transpose[Thread[{#/10^4., {##2}}] & @@@ b],
 Joined -> True,
 PlotLegends -> {Part, SortBy, Pick},
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False,
 FrameLabel -> {"sample length / list length", "timing"},
 BaseStyle -> 18,
 ImageSize -> 500
 ]
```

[image]

**remark(Ulrich Neuman)**:
I just tried to verify this very interesting post. Thereby I removed Sort&Co

```
m1 := list[[ RandomSample[Range[Length[list]], n]]]
m2 := RandomSample[list, n] 
m3 := Pick[list,RandomSample[Join[ConstantArray[0, n], ConstantArray[1, Length[list] - n]]], 0]
```

which gives (Kuba timing)

```
b = Table[{n, m1; // RepeatedTiming // First,m2; // RepeatedTiming // First,m3; // RepeatedTiming // First}, {n, {1, 5, 10, 50, 100, 500,1000, 5000, 10000}}];

ListLogPlot[Transpose[Thread[{#/10^4., {##2}}] & @@@ b],Joined -> True, PlotLegends -> {"m1", "m2", "m3"}, Frame -> True,Axes -> False,FrameLabel -> {"sample length / list length", "timing"},BaseStyle -> 18, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]
and shows   `m2 := RandomSample[list, n]` to be the fastest method!

Comment: Nice one. If you like you can include my idea, as it won't be as fast. But it is a different approach: create a random sample of positions that you *don't* want to pick and `Delete` them: `With[{l = Length[list]},Delete[list, RandomSample[Array[{#} &, l], l - n]] ]`

Comment: Feel free to merge/delete my edit.

Comment: @Urlich Neumann `RandomSample` being faster than code that contains `RandomSample + Part` or `RandomSample + Pick`is not surprising ;)

Comment: @halirutan or create positions that you do wan't and `Take` them, right? A thought to speed `Join[ConstantArray[0, n], ConstantArray[1, Length[list] - n]]` from the `Pick` solution: might `UnitStep[Range[-n,l-n-1]]` be faster?